# Error with returning a Dictionary list with Linq

Tags: c#, dictionary

So i have a method that returns categories but they are listed in a Disctionary list, it gives a convert error at the select statement. This is the first time that i work with a Dictionary. What am i missing?

This is the error i get:
**"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"**

```
 private Task<Dictionary<String, Category>> getCategoriesList()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<Dictionary<String, Category>>(() =>
            {
                var temp = _iDataService.Categories;
                var tempCategoriesList = new Dictionary<String, Category>();

                tempCategoriesList = (from categories in temp
                                      select categories.Value.Name);

                return tempCategoriesList;
            });
    }
```

Comment: what is the type of Categories?

Comment: Check out the `ToDictionary` extension method.

Comment: I added the error and the type is Dictionary<String, Category>

Comment: @user2970725 If `_iDataService.Categories` is already a `Dictionary<stirng, Category>` then what exactly are you trying to accomplish with you're Linq statement?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't return a Dictionary, it [returns an IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
from categories in temp
select categories.Value.Name
```

BTW "temp" and "tempCategoriesList" are awful variable names, and they're absolutely unnecessary. Using [ToDictionary()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/todictionary) these seven lines can be reduced to a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Assumig that `_iDataService.Categories` is a colleciton of `Category` and you want a dictionary of names to `Category` then I think this is what you want.

```
tempCategoriesList = categories.ToDictionary(c=>c.Name);
```

and you can just reduce this to one line

```
return _iDataService.Categories.ToDictionary(c=>c.Name);
```

On the other hand if `_iDataService.Categories` is a `Dictionary<string,Category>` and you basically want to replace whatever the current key is with the `Name` then I think this is what you want.

```
return _iDataService.Categories.ToDictionary(kvp=>kvp.Value.Name, kvp.Value);
```

Comment: Category has id, name, image, ect ect and i need all the Category objects in a list so i can show the Category.Name and Category.Image in a list

Comment: @user2970725 if you want a list then why are you using dictionaries?

Comment: Sorry but i'm kinda new to this sort of lists, but it says kvp.Value doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: @user2970725 Then that means that `_iDataService.Categories` is not a `Dictionary`.  I need to know the type of that property in order to help you.